# check to see if value exists then display different pages based on reply

Tags: android

I have a mysql database set up, i was wondering if it is possible to check the mysql database for a value (e.g. a username) and then report back if the username exists load one activity, if not load another. all of this done on an android app

Thanks

Comment: You can only use SQLite database in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. You can query the database in your Activity's onCreate or onResume and then call StartActivity passing in different Activity classes based on the results of the query.

Comment: do you know how i would go about querying the database?

Comment: If you have SQLite database, you can use a SQLiteOpenHelper (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Comment: No, but you can always put it behind a web service and expose an API. Then call it with HttpClient. There isn't any built-in support for MySQL in Android AFAIK.